# Installation stops about 3/4 of the way through, nothing happens after I click "Skip"

Tags: installation

Okay, at the beginning of the installation, it went well. My laptop is connected to power source, the internet, I have also checked the boxes "install updates while installation", "install third party plugin". After inputting location, keyboard layout info and user's details and password, the installation took place.

But after 3/4 of the installation, it stopped, right above the progress bar, it displayed "installing system", I clicked on the arrow below it, the terminal-like screen also stopped carrying out the process. I then clicked on the "Skip" button, nothing happens.

I thought it was the problem of my laptop, then I did another fresh installation, same thing happened. The terminal-like screen was showing some different words. But it's not an error message, just some installation info.

Does anyone have valuable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The time that "skip" option occurs is usually when  the following happens:

- Downloading updates
- Downloading language packages
- Downloading third-party plugins

The time to complete this tasks depends on your network speed. Usually the packages may be a total of several MB (>=100) so you have to be patient.

If you want a straight foreword simple installation **Do Not** enable "*install updates while installatio*n" and  "*install third party plugin*". You can install them after you have finished the installation

Answer (score 0):

Try again and just let it run until the install completes or you see an actual error message. I've noticed that the servers are much slower than usual right now, undoubtedly due to all the new 12.04 users. And, as Salih mentioned, the language packages are quite large and are retrieved near the end of the install process.

Be prepared for the updates you will likely need to pull down when you first launch your new system to arrive slowly, as well.